# Is 0.1.2.3 a valid IP address?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Are IP addresses with all zeroes in the first octet valid?

For example, can `0.1.2.0/24` be a valid subnet, with network address `0.1.2.0`, broadcast address `0.1.2.255` and an usable address range from `0.1.2.1` to `0.1.2.254`?

It looks like it *should* be valid, but it doesn't work, at least on Windows systems.

If it's not valid, then why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122), *Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers*, says:

```
     { <Network-number>, <Host-number> }

(a)  { 0, 0 }

     This host on this network.  MUST NOT be sent, except as
     a source address as part of an initialization procedure
     by which the host learns its own IP address.

     See also Section 3.3.6 for a non-standard use of {0,0}.

(b)  { 0, <Host-number> }

     Specified host on this network.  It MUST NOT be sent,
     except as a source address as part of an initialization
     procedure by which the host learns its full IP address.
```

Comment: OK, not valid. Is any IP, other than 0.0.0.0 in DHCP, actually used?

Comment: To my knowledge, no.

Comment: It would appear that the intention was that a host might know its own host number, but not its network number, and use this to request that information from a DHCP-like server.  That said, I'm not aware that anything like this ever existed.  It also probably doesn't make a lot of sense in a post-classful world.

Comment: Wow, does it mean, that if I am on a local network, like on 10.5.0.0/16, then I can access the other machines with the IP 10.5.x.y on the same network on the IP 0.0.x.y ?

Answer (score 19):

Looks like 0.0.0.0/8 is in the list of IANA Reserved subnets.

- http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml, the list of IANA reserved addresses, since this one dates far enough back (1981!) to have been an IANA reserved address range.
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735, describing special uses of IPv4, of which this subnet is a member. The most-current list of special subnets, including the subnets reserved for documentation purposes.
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3, which describes the specific usage of the 0/8 network.

Answer (score 13):

Per [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#page-6), 0.0.0.0/8 is a reserved IP address range, as follows:

> 0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
> network.  Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
> host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
> refer to specified hosts on this network [RFC1700, page 4].

Answer (score 11):

According to [RFC 1700 - "Assigned Numbers"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700), "Special Addresses" section, a network number of 0 can only be used as a source address, and represents a host on the same network. Therefore it is invalid to assign an address of this type to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

"0." networks are used for SNM ( SYSTEM NETWORK MANAGEMENT) and can't be used for something else

Comment: Do you have any citations to back this up?  The other answers here includes quotes and links to authorities.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wondering why the Network-number is 0 in this case, 0.1.2.0/24 breaks down as follows:

```
Network = (8 bits) 0
Subnetwork (16 bits) = 1.2
Host part = remaining 8 bits
```

Given that the MSB of the first octet is 0, it must be class A, with an implied network portion of 8 bits.
It is subnetted a further 16 bits (the next two octets).

Given things like CIDR and the death of classful addressing, 0.1.2.0/24 **should** be a valid subnet (there are bits set in the network portion if you consider the first 24 bits).

Answer (score -1):

The IP 0.0.0.0 is used just for request a valid IP Address from DHCP Server, and DHCP server is replying a dynamic valid IP for request computer.